# what is this iOS control called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I cannot find or remember the name of this options control that pops up at the bottom of iOS apps:

[image]

Let me know.

Comment: -1 for not going through the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556) first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is called an `UIActionSheet`. [UIActionSheet Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is correct. @Atma, you can learn about all the controls available in iOS in the Human Interface Guidelines. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html